# From Qt how to send message to a native application

Tags: c++, .net, multithreading, qt

I found a c++ application to create a splash screen. That creates a named event so from another application this application can be closed. I have an example how to close it from a .net application:

```
private void CloseSplashScreen()
    {
        // signal the native process (that launched us) to close the splash screen
        using (var closeSplashEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "CloseSplashScreenEventSplashScreenStarter"))
        {
            closeSplashEvent.Set();
        }
```

Now, I have no idea how to do the same from a qt5 application. I am new to Qt so please, give an example.

Comment: your solution is not multiplatform, so i doubt qt will have api for that. You should probably use winapi

Answer (score 0):

Trying to integrate .Net code into your Qt app just for showing a splash screen: bad idea.

Here's the result of a quick Google search for "qt splash screen".

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_display_a_splash_screen_in_Qt
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsplashscreen.html

Comment: Thanks, I know that. The splash screen is provided by a c++ application. It is not a .net application. Just I found it as an example to use for WPF cold start, this is why I have the solution for a .net application. The reason I did not use the Qt splash screen as it has a problem with transparent background and I want to show a png file with transparency. This was "bug" was not solved in Qt yet. So, do you know how to implement the above code in Qt?

Comment: No Qt wrapper for this. As @10WaRRioR01 said, use the WinAPI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx